# How to set umask globally?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, umask

I am using a private user group setup, i.e. a user `foo`'s home directory is owned by `foo:foo`, not `foo:users`.

For this to work, I need to set the umask to 002 globally.

After a quick `grep -RIi umask /etc/*`, it seemed for a moment that modifying the `UMASK` entry in `/etc/login.defs` should do the trick. It does, too -- but only for *console* logins.

If I log in to my desktop, and open a terminal there, I still get to see the default `umask 022`. Same goes for files created from apps started through the menu. Apparently, the display manager (or whatever X11 component responsible) does source some different setting than a console login does, and damned if I could tell which one it is. (I tried changing the setting in `/etc/init.d/rc`, and no, it did not help.)

How / where do I set `umask` **globally** (and for all users), so that the X11 desktop environment gets the memo as well?

(The system is Linux Mint / Ubuntu, in case that changes anything...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the umask globally by introducing the statement

```
 umask 022
```

(for instance) in either /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc.

Alternatively, since you are on a Debian system, you may use PAM. To enable this, first edit the file `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and add the line:

```
 session optional pam_umask.so
```

then edit the file `/etc/login.defs` and add (or modify, whatever) the line

```
 UMASK           002
```

These settings are enforced after the next reboot, but be careful: both methods lead to a configuration that can always be superseded by users' choice in their own ~/.bashrc, for instance.

If you are really keen on making it impossible to change the umask, you may use the disk configuration in /etc/fstab. As you know, the available options and syntax depend upon the filesystem type.

Comment: I was under the impression that `/etc/profile` wouldn't do for X11, as it would be only sourced by the appropriate *shell* environments. Since this answer *did* work for me, seems I was wrong. ;-) The file I actually ended up editing (as I'm running a Linux Mint / Ubuntu) was `/etc/profile.d/umask`, which is sourced by `/etc/profile` (and results in my edits not getting nuked with the next system update of the latter). Thanks!

Comment: @DevSolar maybe i'm a little bit nitpicking, but i'm pretty sure it has to be a file called `umask.sh` or `whatever.sh` because of the line `for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do` in `/etc/profile`.